# How do I turn this loop into a list comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to turn the following code into a list comprehension to improve compactness. Thanks!

```
grid = {}
for x in range(HOR_SQUARES):
    for y in range(VERT_SQUARES):
        grid[(x,y)] = GridSquare()
```

Answer (score 3):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is nice:

```
from itertools import product
grid = {tup: GridSquare() for tup in product(range(HOR_SQUARES), range(VERT_SQUARES))}
```

and if it really *is* square (`HOR_SQUARES == VERT_SQUARES`) then this is even simpler:

```
grid = {tup: GridSquare() for tup in product(range(HOR_SQUARES), repeat=2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `grid = dict(((x, y), GridSquare()) for x in range(HOR_SQUARES) for y in range(VERT_SQUARES))`

Answer (score 0):

You can go directly to a dictionary using a dict comprehension:

```
grid = {(x, y): GridSquare() for x in range(HOR_SQUARES) for y in range(VERT_SQUARES)}
```

Compactness is nice but once your comprehensions start getting more complex you might
also want to format them a bit:

```
grid = {(x, y): GridSquare() 
        for x in range(HOR_SQUARES)
        for y in range(VERT_SQUARES)}
```